# Better way to model that?

Tags: java, arraylist

This is not an issue but I wonder if my practice is the best.
I have to model a list of `blocs`, ordered from 1 to n, with a duration for each bloc.
something like that.

```
bloc 1    duration 452
bloc 2    duration 12
bloc 3    duration 12585
bloc 4    duration 1
bloc 5    duration 1442
bloc 6    duration 1274
```

the way I found is something like that.

```
private List<Integer> blocDurations = new ArrayList<>();
```

then, to persist durations, i do :

```
blocDurations.add(452);
blocDurations.add(12);
blocDurations.add(12585);
```

and to get duration of bloc n, i do :

```
private int getDurationForBlocNumber(int blocN) {
    return blocDurations.get(blocN - 1);
}
```

all is well but.
is there a better way to do that?

Comment: how do you receive the bloc durations? is it already a list, do you get it per endpoint, etc

Comment: i receive blocs always in the good order : bloc1 with its duration, then bloc2, then bloc3..

Comment: can you please add your data input source - how you get the durations? have you measured it by yourself and you put them in the list by hand? maybe you could use some kind of a file?

Answer (score 0):

- Depending on what you intend to do with the bloc durations, instead of `int` it could be smart to use `java.time.Duration` that comes with [a lot of functionality](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Duration.html).
- If the bloc durations are collected in a non-continuous manner (say bloc 3 should be processed before the first bloc), it could be smart to use a `Map<Integer, Duration>` instead of a `List`.